# After upgrade from TYPO3 7.6.X to 8.7.X I can't save changes from rte editor to the database

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

After the update, I can't save the changes made in the rte/rte_ckeditor (tested on both). Any changes from before the update are loaded correctly but after making any changes and clicking the "save" button, all formatting is cleared and only text in paragraphs `<p>` remain. Similarly with new content element.

Any ideas what causes such an error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason - (wrong) configuration of RTE in TSConfig of my site. The problematic part of the code:

```
RTE.default.proc.transformBoldAndItalicTags = 1
RTE.default.FE.proc.transformBoldAndItalicTags = 1
RTE.default.proc {
   entryHTMLparser_db = 1
   entryHTMLparser_db {
     tags {
       b.remap = strong
       i.remap = em
     }
   }

   exitHTMLparser_db = 1
   exitHTMLparser_db {
     tags.b.remap = strong
     tags.i.remap = em
   }
}
```

Comment: so what was the problem with the configuration? how did you solve it?