# TYPO3: Using rte_ckeditor with entryHTMLparser_db

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, rich-text-editor, typo3-8.7.x

When upgrading from TYPO3 v7 to v8.7, the new `rte_ckeditor` extension is used instead of `rtehtmlarea`.

In TYPO3 7, we used RTE PageTSconfig to filter out unwanted tags and attributes:

```
RTE.default {
    showButtons = bold, strong, emphasis, italic, unorderedlist, orderedlist, link, unlink, chMode
    proc {
        denyTags = blockquote, center, div, font, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, img, nav, pre, span, strike, sub, sup, strike, u

        entryHTMLparser_db = 1
        entryHTMLparser_db {
            removeTags < RTE.default.proc.denyTags
            noAttrib = b, br, div, em, i, li, ol, p, strong, ul
            tags >
            tags.a.allowedAttribs = href,title,target
        }
    }
}
```

When saving a text content element, all the tags get removed.
This can be [worked around by disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51281368/282601) the [entryHTMLparser_db](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/9.5/en-us/PageTsconfig/Rte.html#entryhtmlparser-db) with `entryHTMLparser_db = 0`.

The [manual states](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/8.7/en-us/Configuration/Concepts.html#transformations-vs-ckeditors-advanced-content-filter) that "CKEditor’s Advanced Content Filter" shall be used.

Now my questions:

1. Can I still use `entryHTMLparser_db` in TYPO3 v8+? How?
2. Isn't "advanced content filter" implemented in Javascript and can thus be circumvented by POSTing data to the TYPO3 backend? (which means we lose a security barrier)

Comment: Maybe you have to use allowTags too? I did this stuff in Processing.yaml instead of page TSconfig.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 indeed relied on client side filtering through CKEditor's advanced filtering, as described in https://typo3.org/article/about-the-latest-typo3-core-security-release:

> We used to rely on CKEditor's sanitization logic, but it is using client-side validation that cannot always be trusted. This is now cleaned up and moved to the server side.

The server side validation was implemented in the [security release](https://typo3.org/article/typo3-1132-10419-9529-8742-7653-security-releases-published) versions 11.3.2, 10.4.19, 9.5.29, 8.7.42, 7.6.53 (the TYPO3 v8 and v7 releases were ELTS versions that you have to buy).